# IIS and Vue.JS - Get Windows Authenticated User

Tags: vue.js, windows-server-2016, iis-10

i want to host a VueJS Page for an intranet-Website.
For that i´m running my VueJS App on IIS v10 (Windows Server 2016).
On the IIS i configured only Windows Authentication.

The Website appears, so the Authentication works without typing any user or password.
so far so good ...

But what i have to do, to get the current User?
i can not found any solutions.
with this user i want to control the access, then i don´t need any user management system.
Have someone experience with that?

Comment: You cannot get browser side user credentials without a server side Web API. A C#/ASP.NET example can be found at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-windows-authentication-in-web-api-and-angular-app/

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot get windows user in vue.js.